# Deleting underscore in a SAS column

Tags: sas

I have a data set like this

Country  Year  Value

with a lot of observations. All the years in the column Year are preceded by an underscore, like _1990 for example. But I'd like to delete the underscore because in the other datasets I need it is written like 1990.

I tried the following

```
data x;
set x;
by Year;
replace _ = "";
RUN;
```

But it didn't work. 
I specify that I am new using SAS.

Looking forward for your help,

Comment: I am wondering, What coding background do you have that made you consider the statement `replace _ = "";` as *that might work*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will remove `_` character and create new variable

```
Data want; 
   set have;
     YEAR_NEW=compress(YEAR,"_","i");
 run;
```